# Is it possible to create Azure container service(ACS) through Rest API?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I need to create Azure container service with single azure rest api.
Is it possible? if yes folks please help me

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you only need a Container with no Virtual Machine at all. The following PowerShell Script calls such REST API.

```
Add-Type -Path 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Azure Active Directory Connect\Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.dll'

$tenantID = "<the tenant ID of your Subscription>"
$loginEndpoint = "https://login.windows.net/"
$managementResourceURI = "https://management.core.windows.net/"
$redirectURI = New-Object System.Uri ("urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob")
$clientID = "1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2"
$subscriptionID = "<your subscription id>"

$authString = $loginEndpoint + $tenantID

$authenticationContext = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AuthenticationContext ($authString, $false)

$promptBehaviour = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Auto

$userIdentifierType = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType]::RequiredDisplayableId

$userIdentifier = New-Object Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier ("<your azure account>", $userIdentifierType)

$authenticationResult = $authenticationContext.AcquireToken($managementResourceURI, $clientID, $redirectURI, $promptBehaviour, $userIdentifier); 

# construct authorization header for the REST API.
$authHeader = $authenticationResult.AccessTokenType + " " + $authenticationResult.AccessToken
$headers = @{"Authorization"=$authHeader; "Content-Type"="application/json"}

# Invoke the REST API.
Invoke-RestMethod -Method PUT -Uri "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/$subscriptionID/resourceGroups/<the resource group>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/containerServices/<the container>?api-version=2016-03-30" -Headers $headers -infile containerService.json
```

For the containerService.json, here is a sample of DCOS container.

```
{
  "name": "containerservice-mooncaketeam",
  "type": "Microsoft.ContainerService/ContainerServices",
  "location": "eastasia",
  "properties": {
    "orchestratorProfile": {
      "orchestratorType": "DCOS"
    },
    "masterProfile": {
      "count": 1,
      "dnsPrefix": "jackstestmgmt",
    },
    "agentPoolProfiles": [
      {
        "name": "agentpools",
        "count": 1,
        "vmSize": "Standard_D1",
        "dnsPrefix": "jackstestagents",
      }
    ],
    "linuxProfile": {
      "ssh": {
        "publicKeys": [
          {
            "keyData": "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEArgPsnnGrA2gbmXKEd0O1zWGmiRhfBgmGugAwC7IGcm71RjqoISHz0MKZyJbt/gvX6BKogdCAaN1rDisuOMSsd7LonkURtOJV3RszdAKtk3o+tBtrJy1RhGOIA76/5XQWaCFgoiQGGwF9KYn9VnwjwcQki2OOZIq1YJAkrZxgkNPkMKjVlmsyGJJkpSHyIpzVqZWOYVFP8mon8kll+ZUec+tPK+RYxNZQadxvUzRMvCGdHCGT274KpgnP0FgemrS9/SCJCHW4qZawANp8uBrjLwSTstqmA1uJddZ3RPZu+BgZ68EihF0wG3GsvB4tV0fBYnxRiElYn+FdaZlYbZDobw=="
          }
        ]
      },
      "adminUsername": "admin"
    }
  }
}
```

This REST API will create 1 container Service, 1 availability set, 3 network security groups, and 2 public IP addresses.